# Empty line in Word document's table cells after inserting an image using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm iteratively adding pictures to a new Word document using Python's docx module. It works, but there is an extra line in each table cell. I presume this is the case because the cell already has a paragraph, so adding a new one adds a newline character. However, every example I've seen has recommending the following approach, which seems to be causing the problem:

```
import docx

document = docx.Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=2)

cells = table.add_row().cells
p = cells[0].add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('test.png')
cells[1].text = 'test'

document.save()
```

Here is how the document looks:

[image]

The extra space above the picture is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after looking through the documentation some more. Cells are created with a paragraph by default, which is what I expected. Use the existing paragraph instead:

```
p = cells[0].paragraphs[0]
p.style = None
r = p.add_run(style = None)
```

I set the styles to `None` to remove the default format, which adds a lot of extra whitespace.